# Complete, precise code for autoplaying YouTube video on mobile?

Tags: video, mobile, youtube, youtube-api

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I've redesigned my company's website and am looking for some complete and accurate code for autoplaying the background hero video (hosted from YouTube) on mobile devices.

I should note here that I redesigned the site using Adobe Muse. Yes I know it's no longer supported by Adobe, and yes I know that there are better options. However Muse was my best option in this case and it's what I used. No changing that at this point.

I decided to host the video on YouTube to prevent site bandwidth issues, and after some researching found that the following combination of HTMl and CSS works on desktops for auto-playing the video and making it fully responsive:

```
    <div class="iframe-container">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1&loop=1&playlist=VIDEO_ID&playsinline=1&mute=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&fs=0&controls=0&disablekb=1&modestbranding=1&color=red" width=“720" height=“480" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <style>
    .iframe-container{
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 78%; 
      height: 0;
    }
    .iframe-container iframe{
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    </div>
```

The original plan was to use an image slideshow for screen sizes below 768 pixels wide. But many tablets these days have higher res screens than that, so it makes sense to use code for auto-playing the video on mobile devices as well. I tried adding on this bit of modified code from YouTube's IFrame Player API page (https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters):

```
    <div id="ytplayer"></div>
    <script>
      // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
      // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
          height: ‘100%',
          width: ‘100%',
          videoId: 'VIDEO_ID'
        });
      }
    </script>
```

But for some reason, the video does not auto-play on Android tablet or iPhone. I'm sure the answer is simple and I just missed something that's very easy to fix.

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much!

P.S. Please note that for this post the code shows a generic "VIDEO_ID", but the code has the actual video ID in place.

Answer (score 1):

this question is quite old but since there is no answer and I just found it...

You have to mute the video in order to have the autoplay to work. For example (note the get parameters after the <VIDEO_ID>):

````
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<VIDEO_ID>?autoplay=1&mute=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="max-width:100%"></iframe>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Where did you copy the iframe code from?  If you grabbed it from YouTube - it looks like this:

```
    <iframe width="560" height="315" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<videoID>?loop=1&muted=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" 
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Adding the Allow="autoplay" will get you where you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So you're saying that autoplay=1 isn't enough, and that it also needs allow="autoplay"? I guess after doing that, I don't need that whole second section of code from YouTube's IFrame Player API page...?

Comment: I added allow="autoplay", and re-uploaded to the FTP host to check on iPhone. It is not auto-playing.